# Database design: How to query multiple to multiple table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a system used for exhibition in Website.

The exhibition data maybe from multi-data in difference table.

Like this design:
[image: Table Design]

- > Table [ExhibitionType] used for differentiate category.
- > Table [ExhibitionBase] used for link extra Sub-Type table & data in different table.

My website use MySQL and PHP

Now question is I DON'T KNOW how to query it. or this design have a flaw.

---

**EDIT 1:**

I'm sorry I didn't express my intentions.

Example: I hope query a data list. first i need filter `ExhibitionType` like 1.

So i need create a SQL like :`SELECT * FROM ExhibitionBase WHERE ExhibitionTypeId = 1`

And second step i must read `ExhibitionDataType` and `ExhibitionDataId` each row data. And according to the different types of `ExhibitionData` data out to merge into the `ExhibitionBase` Sub-tables.

HOW TO DO use SQL query it.

This my question.

Comment: There are many things you can query here. Can you please clarify the question by sharing some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: @Mureinik thanks remind.

Comment: Did you mean "never mind"?  If so, please delete the question.

Comment: @RickJames  i mean thanks remind me describe the question. so i edit the question. but no body answer me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT b.*, dt.Name, di.name
    FROM ExhibitionBase AS b
    JOIN ExhibitionDataType AS dt ON dt.id = b.ExhibitionDataType
    JOIN ExhibitionDataId   AS di ON di.id = b.ExhibitionDataId
    WHERE ExhibitionTypeId = 1
```

Style suggestions:

- Do not prefix column and table names with the database name; it clutters things.  ("Exhibition")
- Do not have a column name the same as its table name.